# Rails not finding PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, nitrousio

I am trying to switch my very first Rails app from sqlite to PostgreSQL. I am using a Nitrous box for development and when I tried to switch to Postgre and deploy to Heroku it didn't work so now I'm just trying to use Postgre on Nitrous. I am using Rails 4.1.6.

First I followed these steps:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#use-postgres

But I was getting an error saying "psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory" so I installed psql by following steps no. 4 and 5 from this:

https://gist.github.com/afshinator/8035821

In particular I ran "parts install postgresql" and "parts start postgresql" on my Nitrous box. The postgres version is 9.2.4.

And I also added a line into my database.yml file of "host: localhost" so it now looks like:

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
host: localhost
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
<<: *default
database: db/db_development

...
```

And my Gemfile includes:

```
gem 'pg'
```

My table is called "movies" and if I type "psql db/db_development" and then "select * from movies;" I can see a table. But I can't access this from the Rails console with Active Record.

Comment: have you tried adding database username and password to the default configuration in your database.yml file ?

Comment: I just tried "username: [name of app]" but this did not work. I think maybe I will try testing a new app with postgre

Comment: It's actually the username and password of the account you use to log into Postgres..so by default that would you the account under which you are logged in your system. I had the same issue I following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial to configure an account for Postgres and used its credentials in my rails database configuration

Comment: Well I was able to find [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:z1gCBTNY9eoJ:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) cached version and I am able to add "username: [login]" now and not get a new error, but it still gives the old error

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Nitrous.IO guides? A guide for the Autoparts PostgreSQL db can be found at http://help.nitrous.io/postgresql/ , and a Heroku Postgres example can be found at http://help.nitrous.io/postgres/ .

Comment: Thanks. At first I thought even those guides did not work but that was just me messing up a command :| I solved my problem but only by deleting the database and making a new one. Apparently there was some problem with the migrations.